# Owl carousel isn't working, no error, div dissapears

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I have a problem with Owl carousel. I added the owl.carousel.css , owl.carousel.js and the owl.theme.css . Made a div with the class="owl-carousel". and called the `function $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();`. When I did this my div disappears and I don't get any errors in my console...

Does someone know this? (I use chrome)

I follow this demo: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#more-demos

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
                  <div class="item">                  
                        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item"> 
                        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                  </div>
```

dont mind the empty src.... there are images  in it...

Also another problem appeared :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function?ckcachecontrol=1422871493:74 (anonymous
>   function)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.jjquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
>   m.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery-1.11.2.min.js:2
>   m.extend.readyjquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 J

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var carousel = $("#owl-demo");
    carousel.owlCarousel({

      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });

});
```

its about the function....

Comment: Please add your code or at least part of your code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your settings are correct, if you have a single image by default owl will not work, as it requires more than one image to display the carousel.

Comment: what settings do u mean??

Comment: The default owl settings declared in your JavaScript. Try adding another slide to your carousel if there is only one, as this usually causes it not to display.

Comment: got another problem, read tje question then the last error. i guess thats my mistake here, i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: I would check if all the files needed are added in the correct order first. Check the source code of your page, and make sure jQuery is added first, then Owl Carousel, and last your script file. I would also make sure those are added at the bottom of your page, before the BODY tag.

Comment: Putting the script an link to the bottom helped my problem. thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your id & class, in your html you use a class called ".owl-carousel" and in your javascript you use an id called ".owl-demo".

Use .owl-carousel in your javascript and your carousel will works.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to you have different ids if you want owl-carousel to work in more than one div with the same styling. for example if you have div with an id of #work and the owl-carousel is working, you might be required to name your second div #work-2 to avoid the issue of disappearing.